# Has anybody seen anything on a custom gridview with builtin alpha paging

Tags: asp.net

I have a a custom gridview control that I like to incorpoarate different features as I come across them. Is there a way to access the datasource and the method being used to update the data with clicked letter? I have figured out how to create the alpha links in the footer like so

```
        Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnRowCreated(ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnRowCreated(e)
             If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
                Dim intNoOfMergeCol As Integer = e.Row.Cells.Count
                'except last column 
                For intCellCol As Integer = intNoOfMergeCol - 1 To 1 Step -1
                    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(intCellCol)
                Next
                e.Row.Cells(0).ColumnSpan = Me.HeaderRow.Cells.Count
                For i As Integer = 65 To (65 + 25)
                    Dim lb As LinkButton = New LinkButton()
                    lb.Text = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(i) & " "
                    lb.CommandArgument = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(i)
                    lb.CommandName = "AlphaPaging"
                    e.Row.Cells(0).Controls.Add(lb)
                Next
                e.Row.Cells(0).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left
            End If

    End Sub
```

I can use the rowCommand event to check for the click like so

```
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnRowCommand(ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs)
        If e.CommandName = "AlphaPaging" Then
            'todo
        End If
    End Sub
```

But I am unsure of where to get the data information needed to make the functionality work. Any clues will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I would try and add such a filter or setup to the GV.

I would simple drop the filter below the GV.

And that will save a LOT of work. Better yet, we can use say a control like RadioButton list.

Why?
Well a radio button list automatic ONLY allows one choice, and thus clicking on one letter will highlight, and un-highlight for us automatic.

more why?

The RadioButton list has ONE event - so we don't have to write/wire up a whole bunch of buttons to one event - it done for use

more more why?

RadioButton list, like all asp.net controls can be feed data - just like most controls - so we follow the design pattern to fill out that control like anything else.

more more more why?
We can flip the RadioButton list over to a check box - and now we have multiple filters as possible.

So, say we have this simple grid:

```
    <div style="width:60%;padding-25px">
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table">
            <Columns> 
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"  />
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
```

Ok, code to fill is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT * FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName"
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

And we now have this:

[image]

so, now lets drop in a RadioButton ist - right below the grid.
(I don't think trying to put inside the GV is worth the efforts).

So, we add this mark up -

```
       </asp:GridView>

        <div style="border:solid;border-color:black;border-width:1px;padding:5px;margin-top:-12px">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioAlpha" runat="server" 
            AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
            DataTextField="Value"
            DataValueField="Key" CssClass="rMyChoice"
            AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

So, we drop in that radio button list.

Now, in load grid to the above code, we have this:

```
    Dim bList As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    For i As Integer = Asc("A") To Asc("Z")
        bList.Add(i, Chr(i))
    Next

    bList.Add(0, "All")   ' we need a "all/no filter"
    ' bind this to our radio button list
    RadioAlpha.DataSource = bList
    RadioAlpha.DataBind()
    RadioAlpha.SelectedValue = 0
```

And with that style sheet - we hide the radio button - so only letter shows, and we now have this

[image]

And now the filter code is easy - we have ONE RadioButton event, and our code can be this:

```
Protected Sub RadioAlpha_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioAlpha.SelectedIndexChanged

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM tblHotels"
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            If RadioAlpha.SelectedItem.Text <> "All" Then
                cmdSQL.CommandText &= " WHERE HotelName like @H + '%' "
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@H", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = RadioAlpha.SelectedItem.Text
            End If

            cmdSQL.CommandText &= " ORDER BY HotelName"

            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

So, click on a letter, we get this:

[image]

So not only is the filter code quite easy, but MORE imporant, is the "B" button highlights for us, only one button can be clicked.

So, I don't think I would shove such a filter into the GV.

And we can add/turn on data paging for the above. After all, hitting "all" or some letter certainly could produce more then a page of data.

Comment: I was just wondering if was possible. But after playing around with it, I have come to the conclusion it would be difficult to pass the selected value to the underlying query

Comment: And note how easy my example does just that - passes the selected letter to the query as an parameter. So a good point and all more reason for adoption of my example

Comment: I have already done that at the page level. I was trying to add the functionality at the control level in a custom control. As I have alot of gridview controls, I wanted to add it to the custom control and then it would be available for all the grids

Comment: Sure, you could create a custom control, and add the radbio button list as a control. As you can see - quite a bit less code, but BETTER is how you can only selected one letter. more cool? With the same css, you could use a checkbox list, and thus say click A, F, W, and now your filter could be for all 3. But even with a custom control, we still not trying to put the buttons in the GV.